# authlogic auto_register feature using my options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, openid, authlogic

I have auto registration working with authlogic using gaizka's version of authlogic_openid which I found on Github since pelle's original addition of the feature seemed to cause issues.

http://github.com/gaizka/authlogic_openid

[using authlogic to auto create users bypassing explicit user registeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476953/using-authlogic-to-auto-create-users-bypassing-explicit-user-registeration)

This one works fine however when using the auto_register feature it ignores my options for authlogic such as retrieving the email from the openid provider... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Hhere's the example:

http://big-glow-mama.heroku.com/

http://github.com/holden/authlogic_openid_selector_example/tree/with-facebook/

You can see the difference if you register vs. login...

```
#user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c| 
    c.validate_login_field = false
    # optional, but if a user registers by openid, he should at least share his email-address with the app
    c.validate_email_field = false
    # fetch email by ax
    c.openid_required_fields = [:email,"http://axschema.org/contact/email"]
    #c.required_fields = ["http://axschema.org/contact/email"]
    # fetch email by sreg
    #c.optional_fields = ["email"]
  end

  #private method to deal with emails goes here

end


#UserSession.rb
class UserSession < Authlogic::Session::Base
  auto_register
  logout_on_timeout true
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This one works fine however when using the auto_register feature it ignores my options for authlogic such as retrieving the email from the openid provider... any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

The code that handles auto-registration lives in the authlogic_openid's `Session` module. The code that handles registration (retrieving email form provider, etc), lives in `ActsAsAuthentic` module.

The first is handling a `UserSession` object, the latter is handling a `User` object.

I'll take a look in a couple of days, to see what can be done to merge both behaviours.

Comment: Could you figure out any way of merging the behaviours?

Answer (score 0):

Solved! Thanks to this commit:

http://github.com/mreinsch/authlogic_openid/commit/4a1f644be36aec75ae2d35121904b5a846354233

**by mreinsch.**

Check out the example app here: http://github.com/shripadk/authlogic_openid_selector_example

Live example: http://testingauth.heroku.com/